# Python Regex Search Ignore String

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to preform a regex search in python. I have a string which can be either domain.com/user or domain.com/123

However I want to preform a match if the string is domain.com and /user is NOT found.

```
import re
re.search('domain.com!(/user)',src,re.IGNORECASE)
```

Can you please assist,
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a [negative look-ahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions).

```
import re

print bool(re.search("domain.com(?!/user/)", "domain.com"))
print bool(re.search("domain.com(?!/user/)", "domain.com/user/test"))
print bool(re.search("domain.com(?!/user/)", "domain.com/test"))
```